# Can't implement protected interface from superclass in another package

Tags: java, android

Why can a protected interface from a superclass in another package not be implemented in Java/Android? When the parent and the child are in the same package the code below will work. A short explanation is given below:

Parent.java

```
package package.example;

public class Parent {

    protected interface MyInterface {
        void method();
    }

    protected void protectedMethod() {

    }
}
```

Child.java

```
package package.example.child;

import package.example.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent implements Parent.MyInterface { //not possible

    @Override
    public void method() {

    }

    @Override
    public void protectedMethod() {
        //This works
    }
}
```

The above code will give the warning: *'package.example.Parent.MyInterface' has protected access in 'package.example.Parent'*. Can someone explain to me why this is not possible?

Comment: because it is protected. it's nested in parent, it's not a member of parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)

Comment: @PedroH yes and no. he assumes that since Child extends Parent, Child has access to the protected interface declared in Parent

Comment: I have edited the question. The code works when both Parent and Child are in the same package. Also when I have a protected method in my Parent that is overridden by Child the code will build.

Comment: http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2012/04/public-protected-and-private-interfaces.html give just an example, but no explanation at all.